# Pattern matching an NSDictionary in an NSArray with Swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I have this code in a playground

```
import UIKit

let anArray = NSArray(array:[["code": "LT","name": "Lithuania"], ["code": "ME","name": "Montenegro"], ["code": "ES","name": "Spain"]])

let findCode = "ES"

for object in anArray {
    if (object["code"] as String == findCode) {
        object["name"] as String
    }
}
```

and I would like to simplify it in some way with patter matching, is that possible?

Comment: What is it doing? Are you trying to filter the array?

Comment: Finding in the array of dictionaries what the name is for a certain code. I guess yes.

Comment: OK, just wanted to check. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I created this in a playground...

```
import UIKit

let array : [[String: String]] = [["code": "LT","name": "Lithuania"], ["code": "ME","name": "Montenegro"], ["code": "ES","name": "Spain"]]

let findCode = "ES"

let filteredArray = array.filter{$0["code"] == findCode}

println(filteredArray) // [["code": "ES", "name": "Spain"]]
```

It uses the filter function instead of iteration.

filteredArray will be an array of objects where `object["code"] == findCode`

**EDIT - If you know there is only one**

```
...
let foundObject = array.filter{$0["code"] == findCode}.first

println(foundObject) // ["code": "ES", "name": "Spain"]
```

You could go even further by doing...

```
...
let country = array.filter{$0["code"] == findCode}.first?["name"] // updated, thanks @MikeS

if let unwrappedCountry = country {
    println(unwrappedCountry) // "Spain"
}
```

Comment: Nice catch using `filter`!

Comment: @Zaph thanks :D I'm still new to Swift but it's so ridiculously powerful.

Comment: I guess this works, I had an NSArray originally so doing let swiftArray = anArray as [[String: String]] will just solve that problem. I was looking for someway to do it with pattern matching if its' possible, this is harder to read for me than the loop I had.

Comment: @GerardDiaz when you say "patter" matching. Do you mean "pattern" matching? If so could you explain what sort of thing you were after? Which bit is harder to read? I can add comments if necessary.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. Something like for object in anArray where ["code": findCode,"name": _] (doesn't work obviously)

Comment: @GerardDiaz is that even a thing in Swift? I don't think it is. But this code does what you want in pretty much one line of code.

Comment: @Fogmeister it would be safer to use `.first` instead of `[0]`. `.first` returns an optional containing the first element in the array, or nil if the array is empty. Then you can do the filtering, indexing, and unwrapping in one shot: `if let languageName = array.filter({ $0["code"] == findCode }).first?["name"] { ... }`

Comment: Note: Objective-C Foundation also has an array filter method: `- (void)filterUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate`.

Comment: @Fogmeister I know pattern matching is a thing in swift, see http://realm.io/news/swift-enums-pattern-matching-generics/#expression-operator-1528javascriptpresentzchangechapter016true

Comment: @GerardDiaz yeah, but that's only when using switch blocks I think.

Comment: @Fogmeister that would be a shame then, pattern matching is pretty.

Comment: I'm not sure what pattern you would be matching though. If you know the code then you just need to check equality not pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the `NSArray` on the outside, fold your array of dictionaries to a dictionary that maps a code to a name, and do a fast look-up in it, like this:

```
let aDict = [
    ["code": "LT","name": "Lithuania"]
,   ["code": "ME","name": "Montenegro"]
,   ["code": "ES","name": "Spain"]
]
let dict = aDict.reduce(Dictionary<String,String>()) {
    (var dict, e) in
    dict[e["code"]!] = e["name"]!
    return dict
}
print(dict["ES"]!)
```

Comment: Ah, I thought about using `reduce` but I didn't know enough about how it works.